# Rig acting like camera?

Tags: animation, camera

Here’s a video of what happens: https://streamable.com/0u7ra7

The only addons I have used in the animation are (technically) B.L.E.N.D - Armature Rigging Modules and the Spring Bones addon, I have 0 idea of why this could be or is happening. It has never happened to me before and I can’t find answers online.

Whenever I press 0 instead of going on the camera it should, it goes under the rig. There are no other cameras present and whenever I delete everything but the camera it goes to the camera it should. Setting the camera as an active camera doesn't work, it'll just go under the rig again. I've also tried deleting the rig which will make it so it'll go to the camera it should.

Heres some links to the addons that were used, and the blend file itself:

Spring Bones addon:
https://github.com/artellblender/springbones

Armature Rigging Modules: https://jimkroovy.gumroad.com/l/ArmatureRiggingModules

Blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19iHbzgkPVh9669QGbVj-TAXrVVwF5t4J/view?usp=sharing

**Editing it again ...** I fixed it. I just appened it to another file and it worked

Comment: It is quite hard to understand what is happening in your video. Also external link is not accepted as a main source of info. Please Describe it closer or add some screens we can understand better to your situation. Or attach your blend file, probably just with the camera (try to delete a rest of scene and share if issue will persist. It looks like some unwanted keyframe (of camera or what camera. is used for given frame as active).

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @vklidu I've given a written explanation and links to the addons and blend file. I suggest you download the addons and the blend file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Moving to a new file is solution, but not explanation of your issue :)*

In Blender any object can be used as "camera" ... in your case if you go to *Scene Properties > Scene > Camera* you can see your armature object *Classic_Springtrap* is set.

[image]

Switching to Camera object (you already tried it, to make it active) worked temporarily just because your armature is using "Bind Camera to Markers" in timeline at frame 1.

[image]

To fix that just click on Camera icon and Delete (X).

Binding is very useful to switch cameras due animation.
You probably accidentally pressed ctrl(or cmd)+B in Timeline instead of 3Dview.